# Trouble working with classList add and remove in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In my component, I have the `useEffect` hook adding event listeners to the range function, in order to chage the color of the slider. I can only get pink to work all over the place, and blue at the wrong end of the slider.

In the console.log(), I'm seeing all the classes listed, but only pink seems to work. Thank you.

### component

```
  const range = (r) => {
    // move gradient
    r.addEventListener('input', () => {
      // Change slide thumb color on way up
      if (r.value > r.max * 0.20) {
        r.classList.add('pink')
      }
      if (r.value > r.max * 0.40) {
        r.classList.add('purple')
      }
      if (r.value > r.max * 0.60) {
        r.classList.add('ltpurple')
      }
      if (r.value > r.max * 0.80) {
        r.classList.add('blue')
      }

      // Change slide thumb color on way down
      if (r.value < r.max * 0.20) {
        r.classList.remove('pink')
      }
      if (r.value < r.max * 0.40) {
        r.classList.remove('purple')
      }
      if (r.value < r.max * 0.60) {
        r.classList.remove('ltpurple')
      }
      if (r.value < r.max * 0.80) {
        r.classList.remove('blue')
      }
      // window.requestAnimationFrame(r)
      console.log(r.classList)
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('range')).map(r => range(r))
  })
```

### JSX

```
  <div className="row">
        <h3>Grooming</h3>
        <p>Care and health: hair, ears, mouth, nose, lips, face, hands, nails, feet, toes.</p>
        <input type="range" className="range blue"
          min={0} max={100} name="grooming" onBlur={handleBlur} />
        <p>Well groomed: hair, nails, ears, face, hands.</p>
      </div>
      <div className="row">
        <h3>Hygiene</h3>
        <p>Hygiene education and awareness. Routine and other daily practices.</p>
        <input type="range" className="range blue" onBlur={handleBlur}
          min={0} max={100} name="hygiene" />
        <p>Demonstrates appropriate hygiene practices.</p>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not recommended directly manipulating dom with React. You can put input value in ur component state and the class can be an output depending on the state

```
const [v, setV] = useState(0)

return (
  <div className="row">
        <h3>Grooming</h3>
        <p>Care and health: hair, ears, mouth, nose, lips, face, hands, nails, feet, toes.</p>
        <input type="range" value={v} onChange={e => setV(e.target.value)} className={getClassNameFnc(v, 0, 100)}
          min={0} max={100} name="grooming" onBlur={handleBlur} />
        <p>Well groomed: hair, nails, ears, face, hands.</p>
      </div>
)
```

implement getClassNameFnc as a function that returns the classname, e.g.

```
function getClassNameFnc(v, min, max) {
  if(v > max * 0.20) {
    return 'pink'
  }
  ...
}
```